# Copy a database table to flat file using unix shell and perl

Tags: database, perl, shell, sap-ase

I need to backup a database table to flat file. Generally this can be done with ETL tools. However, I can only use shell scripts and perl out here.

I am using Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise/12.5.0.1

Comment: You haven't mentioned what database you're using. Also, see the [instructions for asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Tell us what you've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise/12.5.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want [SQL::Translator](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL%3a%3aTranslator), it has [a recipe for dumping a database to a structured format](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL%3a%3aTranslator%3a%3aManual#CREATING-A-DATA-DUMPER-SCRIPT)